# Enabling debug prints for LIGHTTPD server

Tags: server, lighttpd, error-logging

I was setting up a ***lighttpd*** server in my ***ARM*** device. Server was set successfully. Now I enabled all the debug prints in the ***lighttpd*** config file for tracking the server activities. All these debug  prints can be seen in an error.log file.  Is there some way that i can print these logs directly to my terminal as they happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since lighttpd is designed to be run as a service I suspect the best way to achieve this would be to run [tail -f](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) on error.log. This may not be ideal as if you have multiple virtual hosts running on one lighttpd install you will have every sites debug log in amongst the wanted messages. Sadly, there is currently no way to have a separate error log for each vHost, although this has been [requested as a feature](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/665).